# Claiming coupons

Tags: c#, entity-framework, finance, asp.net-web-api

I am currently creating a system that allows a user to claim a coupon, after the coupon is claimed the receive currency on their account.

I recently ran into an issue in which if 2 requests with the same coupon code were fired at almost the exact same time my web service call would accept both (probably because of the time it takes to write to the database).

**The code with the problem:**

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

var coupon = Context.Coupons.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Code == code && c.Deleted == false);

if (coupon == null)
    return BadRequest("The code you entered does not belong to a coupon.");

coupon.UserId = userId;
coupon.Deleted = true;

await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

Give the user balance...

return Ok();
```

**My fix:**

```
lock (lockObj)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var coupon = Context.Coupons.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Code == code && c.Deleted == false);

    if (coupon == null)
        return BadRequest("The code you entered does not belong to a coupon.");

    coupon.UserId = userId;
    coupon.Deleted = true;

    Context.SaveChanges();

    Give the user balance...
}

return Ok();
```

So my question: Is this a legitimate way to fix this? I am afraid it will become an issue if a lot of people are claiming coupons at the same time. Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: Are any of your methods async?

Comment: @xDaevax They were, however making them sync didn't change anything (already did that in the first code snippet).

Comment: I ask because using await within a lock statement is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612602/why-cant-i-use-the-await-operator-within-the-body-of-a-lock-statement

Comment: Rather than Context.SaveChanges(); have a method that returns true if the update was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is maybe. If this is the only code that updates it then you will be fine but you are making a gateway that only one person can update at a time even if they have different codes.  If your site gets big you will have performance problems.

You should have your database handle the concurrency when possible.  If using SQL you should use the rowversion field or timestamp field if older SQL.  Then configure your entity with the [TimeStampAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or if using fluent then the [isconcurrencytoken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.isconcurrencytoken(v=vs.113).aspx) method.  This value will change automatically by SQL every time a field has been changed.  Entityframe work will use this and throw an [OptimisticConcurrencyException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.optimisticconcurrencyexception.aspx) if you update and that value has changed.  You can trap for that error and know that the data has changed since you have retrieved that data.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to handle lock issues like that might be a bad idea, because the issue still exists when sclaing sideways (adding new servers/instances).

I would suggest either using concurrency methods in SQL (as suggested by [@CharlesNRice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154205)) or using some message queue solution which is designed to handle concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework transactions are a part of its internal architecture. The "SaveChanges()" method operates within a transaction and saves results of the work.

```
   using (var context = Context)
   using (var dbcxtransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
   {
                    try
                    {
             //         coupon code here
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        dbcxtransaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        dbcxtransaction.Rollback();
                    }
     }
```